# trying to deploy app to heroku recieving error everytime

Tags: ruby, heroku, github

i am currently trying to deploy an app to heroku 
https://github.com/Shopify/dashing/wiki/How-to%3A-Deploy-to-Heroku

I am following these instructions exactly

```
bundle install
git init
git add .
git commit -m "My beautiful dashboard"

heroku apps:create myapp

git push heroku master
```

and receive this error everytime

```
git push heroku master
Counting objects: 441, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (225/225), done.
Writing objects: 100% (441/441), 503.88 KiB | 445 KiB/s, done.
Total 441 (delta 170), reused 441 (delta 170)

-----> Heroku receiving push
-----> Ruby app detected
 !
 !     Gemfile.lock is required. Please run "bundle install" locally
 !     and commit your Gemfile.lock.
 !
 !     Heroku push rejected, failed to compile Ruby app
```

Answer (score 1):

you don't have a Gemfile.lock file
try
`bundle install` and then `git commit -am "message you wanna put here"`

as mentioned below, check the `gitignore` and remove `/Gemfile.lock` and the commit again may resolve your problem

Comment: i have the gemfile.lock in my local repo after running bundle install but when i run git commit -am "message here" i receive this# On branch master
nothing to commit (working directory clean)

Comment: You'll want to commit the lock file too. git add gemlike.lock

Comment: I am running the command git add gemfile.lock but when I attempt to commit it I receive the error I posted above " nothing to commit"

Comment: quite strange, show the result of `git status`, see if you really miss  something.

Comment: oh ... I see, check your `gitignore` , delete the `/Gemfile.lock`, that's the reason you can't commit... so just commit again

Comment: git status returns        # On branch master
nothing to commit (working directory clean)

Comment: i deleted /gemfile.lock from the gitignore. that solved the problem! thanks